# Where do I find all GRUB options?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, documentation

I am looking for a list of all GRUB2 options with an explanation and all possible values.

I tried it [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB/) and [there](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-documentation.html). But I am missing options like:

```
net.ifnames
biosdevname
acpi_enforce_resources
```

I am on  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS/32 with 4.4.0-59.

Comment: Yes, probably kernel parameter. I mean all options which I can use in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: You can add kernel boot parameters in `/etc/default/grub` and set GRUB-specific options there too. Which do you want?

Comment: All, kernel and boot parameter. It is fine with me if this are then two lists.

Answer (score 3):

The most detailed guides I can find are:

[Kernel Boot Command-Line Parameter Reference](http://files.kroah.com/lkn/lkn_pdf/ch09.pdf)
from Greg Kroah-Hartman's book, [Linux Kernel in a Nutshell](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/) (should be a pretty durable link)

and

[The kernel.org boot parameter documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt)

These contain many possible boot parameters with explanations of what they do, but neither seems to be exhaustive.

[@Anwar](https://askubuntu.com/users/61218/anwar) also helpfully pointed out

[The GNU GRUB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html)

which is quite extensive, although my interpretation of your question is that you want to know about kernel params you can pass via `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` rather than configuring GRUB itself.